# What are the obstacles in today's object detection?

Tags: nlp, computer-vision, object-detection

I have read papers about faster RCNN and RFCN, also read YOLO. It seems the biggest problem is the speed? And all of them use image data data only. Are there any models that combines text and image data? Which means we can use the information from text to help detection when the training data is small. For example, when the training data is small, the model cannot tell dogs and cats clearly, but the model could tell there is a bone near that object, and the model gets some information from text that the object near a bone is most likely a dog, thus the model now could tell what the object is. Does this kind of algorithm exist?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mostly referred to research on Deep Networks for Object Detection. Prior to the success of deep networks, researchers were looking to to the possibility of using text with image features to implement ideas similar to yours. You might want to refer to papers from ACM Multimedia and IEEE TMM, especially those before 2014.

The problem was that those approaches could not perform as well as the simplest of the deep networks that use only images. There is some work on combining both images and text, such as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09534.pdf). I am sure at least some researchers are already working on this.